# Lower CP but higher damage? (My confusion over attack damage )

Tags: pokemon-go

I have two Goldducks:

[image]

They have :

**Compat Power 1432 :** (this one was from powering up then evolved Pysduck)

[image]

**Compat Power 1256:** (this one caught in the wild)

[image]

My question is which one will produce more damage to opponent in fighting?
To be honest till level 16 I had never realized all of these values since I though Compat Power will mean everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this website](http://eurogamer.net/articles/2016-08-02-pokemon-go-moves-movesets-move-list-and-highest-dps-attacks), looking up the entry about Golduck, you'll find the following values:

> **Standard moves**:
>
> Water Gun 12 damage per second
>
> Confusion 9.93 damage per second
>
> **Special moves**:
>
> Hydro Pump 23.68 damage per second
>
> Ice Beam 17.81 damage per second.

So, by looking at your first Golduck with the move *Water Gun* `6`, and seeing that it deals 12 damage per second, this tells you, that you can use Water Gun two times per second. Confusion on the other hand deals 15 damage but has "only" 9.93 DPS, so therefore it takes `9.93dps/15d = 0.662 seconds`. Therefore, **Water Gun is faster, and also deals more DPS**.

That's the way to calculate how fast a move is, and now that you know it, you should be fine.

Nevertheless I suggest you to keep both, as it depends highly upon your situation whether you want to have a *Hydropump* or an *Icebeam*. *Icebeam* is especially useful against Dragonite.

Comment: You can edit answers, you know.

Comment: really2 helpful, thank your so much man!

Comment: Golduck will get STAB for water gun but not confusion which makes it even better as well. Also confusion takes 1.51 seconds to attack, not .662 seconds. To put it in the same terms as water guns 2 attacks per second, confusion does .662 attacks per second. Or the other way around water gun attacks every .5 seconds and confusion every 1.51 seconds.

Comment: Ya. It took bit longer than 0.662 second, I've just tested it againts Vaporeon, it was slow.

Comment: Welp, I've never been strong in maths, but hope that the informational value helped :)

Answer (score 0):

It's important to know **the difference** between attacks.

As you may have noticed, Pokemon Go supports *real time* battles, as in the previous Pokemon Games, the battles were *round based* (so one attack per round). The initial Speed attribute of Pokemons was used to determine who gets to attack first. In Pokemon Go this is missing.

The main difference to Pokemon Go is, **that in Pokemon Go attacks also have a certain amount of time that they consume.**
So i.e. the attack *scratch* was usually 40 dmg and 100 accuracy in the first gen, a not-very-useful attack. In Pokemon Go, Scratch does have a very good 12dps (damage per second). --> The usus is to take the dmg an attack has and also the time it uses.

**So don't get confused over the bare valuet that's written at the end of the attack, important is its *dps*.**

For a complete list, you may want to checkout [this website](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2016-08-02-pokemon-go-moves-movesets-move-list-and-highest-dps-attacks) which contains a list of all Pokemons, which moves they can learn and how much dps each move deales.

TL;DR In Pokemon Go efficiency of attacks are calculated as dps (damage per second). The faster an attack is, the more often you can spam it and therefore **attack and it's speed** matter.

Comment: So for you, which one is quicker in term of attack, my first or second golduck?